# introducir consulta SQL en un input con PHP

Tags: php, sql, html5

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a una BDD con php para mostrar los resultados  a través de un input de HTML.

Para mostrar el resultado hago lo siguiente:

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $emp = $fila['Emp_Nom'];
{
```

Y lo muestro a través del input así:

```
 <input type="text" readonly value=<?php echo $emp ?>>
```

El código me muestra el texto pero solamente la primera palabra hasta donde haya un espacio.

Para tratar de resolverlo en vez de usar un `input` he usado un `textarea`y lo he modificado con css para que tenga la misma apariencia que el `input`. 


Hay alguna forma de poder introducir los resultados completos de una consulta en el `input`?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hay estas sacando Emp_Nom que otro resultado quieres mostrar en el imput ?

Comment: y que funciones esta destinado el imput ?

Comment: cojo el valor de Emp_Nom y lo paso al input mostrandolo con `echo $emp` . Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar los datos rescatados de la base de datos en un input.

Comment: eso lo se amigo, la pregunta es que te arroja el codigo  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes concatenar unas comillas simples a la variable $emp así:

```
 <input type="text" readonly value=<?php echo "'" . $emp . "'" ?>>
```

De este modo el input muestra todo el contenido de la variable.

Comment: lo que buscabas es concatenar texto junto con los datos que almacenastes en la variable $emp ?, eso era

Comment: El problema es que la variable $emp era una cadena con espacios y al tratar de mostrarla en el input unicamente aparecía la primera palabra antes de un espacio.

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo ese tipo de problema tendria que verlo para tener idea pero bueno si eso se lo soluciono me alegro

Answer (score 1):

También, si tienes habilitado en tu etc/php/php.ini el Short Tag

short_open_tag = On

Pudieras hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
<input type="text" readonly value="<?=$emp?>">
```

O

```
<input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $emp;?>">
```